# How to update JSON file in database using fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I currently have this function to add a JSON file to the database :

```
  const history = useNavigate();
    function addLoggbokHandler(loggbokData){
        fetch(
            "api/objects.json",
            {
                method: "POST",
                body: JSON.stringify(loggbokData),
                headers:{
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                }
            }
            ).then(() =>{
                history(0);
            });
    }
```

and this function to get all the items from the database to render

```
 const[isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
 const[loadedLoggboks, setLoadedLoggboks] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        fetch(
            "api/objects.json",
        ).then(response => {
            return response.json();
        }).then(data => {
            const loggboks = [];

            for(const key in data)
            {
                console.log(key);
                console.log(data);
                const loggbok = {
                    id: key,
                    ...data[key]
                };

                loggboks.push(loggbok);
            }

            setIsLoading(false);
            setLoadedLoggboks(loggboks);
        });
    }, [])
```

What can I do if I want to interact with specified JSON file in the database using id, to update/change its values? any help is welcome

Comment: Make a new function named "updatebokHandler" and pass id as a parameter in it. this newly created function code is mostly similar to "add into database" code with minor changes. just  change method to PUT and API URL will be like this: `api/objects/${id}.json`. and, It will work.

Comment: thanks alot couldnt find anything on the web for some reason, would mark your comment as acceptable answear if i could :)

Comment: I have given full solution below, accept that answer if you could :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code for update function.

```
function updatebokHandler(id, loggbokData) {
  fetch(`api/objects/${id}.json`, {
    method: "PUT",
    body: JSON.stringify(loggbokData),
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  }).then(() => {
    // Perform any necessary actions after the update is successful
  });
}
```

Change endpoints and data according to your needs